# Writing a Google Chrome extension for an aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to know if someone can point me in the correct direction for this. I've been interested in writing a chrome extension to improve my workflow since we use a lot of webapps at my job. For example, my jobs ticketing system is pretty old and requires that we look manually for any changes or updates. It's got email notifications built in, but they are slow and unreliable.

I've never written chrome extensions before so I looked at some tutorials but none of them give me any information about doing this on an aspx page. Since I don't have direct access to the server this runs from, I thought it should be possible to do something from my end such as automatically refreshing the page using the page's refresh button instead of the browsers refresh button, or automatically opening some collapsed menus which default to being collapsed when you refresh the page.

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to go about doing this because so far my research hasn't given me anything I can directly apply to this issue.

Comment: You need a *content script* where you can use standard DOM stuff on the web page. Take another look at the tutorials and sample extensions that showcase this aspect of extensions.